# PHP install method in a class what requires database tables/columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, methods, installation

I was wondering how does you guys write your classes when they need tables in the database to function or some other things to do before it functions?

Do you use a method to insert the tables in the database or do you write the class to require some columns in a table which can be define at some settings variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the answer to this question is a matter of opinion, I would generally create them in the class constructor (checking whether they exist first or not), however I would allow the user to specify their own names and prefixes to avoid clashes and data loss within their database.

The reason being is that you have total control over how the tables are constructed as opposed to trusting the user to generate them correctly.

This is assuming your class will be used by other people, if it is solely for your own use it is safe enough to assume you are able to build the tables yourself and could remove that overhead from the class.

It also depends what your class is for, if it is a plugin then you should definitely create these for the user so they don't have to touch the underlying code, following any of the database naming conventions of the system your plugin is integrating with.

This is just my personal style and is by no means a standard or necessarily the optimum way.

Comment: Adding a check in the __constructor wouldn't that be a wasted MySQL call? Wouldn't a check of the type of error then trying to access the table in some method have the fallback of trying to inserting the tables if the error says the table don't exists? Yes it a matter of opinion but interesting to see what other do, I'm very curious.

Comment: @Andreas It depends on your application. There is no one place to put anything. I would imagine you save more time calling it once per use instead of every time you wish to operate on the database. It's certainly not going to be much of an overhead unless you have latency connecting to the database, in which case that should be fixed first. With no information on the nature of your application it is impossible to provide such a specific insight. That is just a generalized statement, e.g., if I'm writing a  WordPress plugin I would add a hook to create the table at plugin activation.

Comment: You might miss understand me it would only execute the method if the task at hand would fail and the error message would say that the table don't exists. This is just a general question but yes it comes from that I never really felt that my solution with a install method has been a good idea. I do like the WP plugin activation function which this is inspired from I guess.